# How to create a transparent bitmap in Direct2D

Tags: c++, directx, transparency, direct2d, pixelformat

I need to create a transparent bitmap using Direct2D and draw, by using my device context, on it.

```
ID2D1DeviceContext1* d2dContext = ...
ID2D1Bitmap* pBitmap;

d2dContext->CreateBitmap(
    bitmapSize,
    nullptr,
    0,
    D2D1::BitmapProperties1(
        D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET,
        D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED),
        dpiX, dpiY),
    &pBitmap);

d2dContext->BeginDraw();
d2dContext->SetTarget(pBitmap);
d2dContext->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(0, 0));
d2dContext->DrawLine(...);
hr = d2dContext->EndDraw();
```

Unfortunately I am not able to create any transparent bitmaps. I tried with several [pixel format combinations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756766(v=vs.85).aspx), including `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_STRAIGHT`, but without succeeding.

Is there any solution?

Comment: How do you know that the image is not transparent?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Because I draw the background of my render target before creating the bitmap. And only after I draw this new bitmap over everything else, without clearing the render target. And I can see that the new bitmap covers everything below.

Comment: Then maybe it has something to do with how you draw it. Is alpha-blending enabled? Can you draw transparent bitmaps in general?

Comment: @NicoSchertler I draw the bitmap I by using the `DrawBitmap` method of my `ID2D1DeviceContext1`. The procedure is: 1) I draw several shapes on my target 2) I change the target to the bitmap (created with alpha mode) 3) I draw several shapes on the bitmap 4) I change the target to the original one 5) I draw the bitmap How can I enable alpha blending? No I can't draw transparent bitmaps in general (please be more specific).

Comment: I just know that you have to specify blending explicitly in D3D. Not sure how it is in D2D. The `DrawBitmap` method has an opacity parameter. Try to reduce opacity and see if the result changes.

Answer (score 2):

Good news Nick:  You are creating transparent bitmaps, however the reason why you are not seeing your expected results has to do with window creation.  Kenny Kerr demonstrated proper layered window creation [with Direct2D back in 2009 here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/ee819134).

Since then much has changed with respect to windows rendering, with Win8 and Win10 using a composition engine, and allowing developers access to the DirectComposition API.  As a result, Kenny Kerr provided [an updated article in 2014](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/dn745861.aspx) on the topic.

My recent projects required Win7 support, so I personally stick with pure Direct2D.

**EDIT:**  And of course ensure your [render target is properly created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603276/how-do-i-clear-a-direct2d-render-target-to-fully-transparent).  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do in [Sciter](http://sciter.com/) when I need to create cached rendering (bitmap) :

```
ID2D1RenderTarget* src = ...
d2d::asset<ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget> dst = nullptr;

// creating temp surface - compatible render target:
src->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(sz,dst.target());

dst->BeginDraw();
dst->Clear(init_color);

... drawing on that temp surface ...
dst->EndDraw();

d2d::asset<ID2D1Bitmap> dst_bmp;
hr = dst->GetBitmap(il->d2d_bmp.target());

return dst_bmp;
```

This method delegates bitmap creation to the ID2D1RenderTarget and so that bitmap will always be compatible with source. The code is used with transparent init_color's mostly.

I wouldn't use `SetTarget()` as it is not clear what it does with clips, etc.